# CUDA 2D Convolution kernel

Tags: cuda, convolution

I'm a beginner in CUDA and I'm trying to implement a Sobel Edge detection kernel.
I'm using this code for it but it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it. I just get some -1's and some really big values.

```
__global__ void EdgeDetect_Hor(int *gpu_Edge_Hor, int *gpu_P, 
        int *gpu_Hor, int W, int H)
{ 
    int X = threadIdx.x; 
    int Y = threadIdx.y; 

    int sum = 0; 
    int k1, k2; 
    int min1, min2; 

    for (k1 = 0; k1 < 3; k1++) 
        for(k2 = 0; k2 <3;k2++) 
            sum += gpu_Hor[k1*3+k2]*gpu_P[(X-k1)*H+Y-k2]; 

    gpu_Edge_Hor[X*H+Y] = sum/5000;
}
```

I call this kernel like this:

```
dim3 dimBlock(W,H);
dim3 dimGrid(1,1);
EdgeDetect_Hor<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(gpu_Edge_Hor, gpu_P, gpu_Hor, W, H);
```

Comment: Thank you I'm processing a video with 480x720 frames

Comment: Your kernel is never running because the block size your have is illegal. See Appendix F of the Cuda C Programming guide for the block size limits.

Comment: In the future, run your program through cuda-gdb on Linux, the cuda debugger. You don't really have to code via guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your problem is that you process image of 480x720 pixels. CUDA supports maximum size of thread block 1024 for compute capability 2.0 and greater and 512 for previous. So you can't execute so many threads in one block. The line `dim3 dimBlock(W,H);`  is incorrect. You should divide your threads to several blocks.

Another problem is that CUDA process data in row-major order. So you should change you memory access pattern.

Right memory access pattern for 2D arrays in CUDA is

```
BaseAddress + width * Y + X
```

where

```
unsigned int X = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int Y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

Comment: Thank you I made these changes : dim3 dimBlock(32,32); dim3 dimGrid(19,19);  and also changed my addressing pattern. It very much better now( I actually see something!) but there are some blocks that have some vertical blank bars. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: Did you check if you thread indexes smaller then actual image size?

Comment: I used 18 blocks instead of 19 to make sure of that but the output didn't change also these bars appear in the middle of the frame. So I don't think that's it.

Comment: It's solved thank you. It was dimGrid(23,15); You were very helpful!